# How to revoke the task while running

Tags: python, celery, task

When I send a task and I try to revoke:

```
app=Celery()
app.control.revoke(task.id)
#or
app.control.revoke(task.id, terminate=True)
```

I get that error:

```
[2019-09-05 05:27:50,110: ERROR/MainProcess] pidbox command error: NotImplementedError("<class 'celery.concurrency.gevent.TaskPool'> does not implement kill_job",)
```

I'm using gevent.

```
celery -A MyApp worker -l info -P gevent
```

what's wrong?

Comment: can you provide configuration about celery app, working environment like we're u trying on windows or Unix based system

Comment: configuration about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gevent concurrency does not allow killing of the jobs. Pre-fork does allow it as it is as simple as killing the worker-process that is running the task that you want to terminate, same goes for threading.

There is an issue about this, with a proposed solution - https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4019 - but nobody made a PR.

Comment: If you remove `-P gevent` it will run in the default, pre-fork concurrency, mode.

Comment: error alternative='Please use RPC backend or a persistent backend.')

Comment: Well, that error has nothing to do with the original question. It looks like you did not configure Celery properly.